# path of socket.io doesnt working in the html script tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, socket.io

I am not very much experienced in js and i am not able to understand why the script tag path doesnt work for me whereas i found everywhere that script but for me it doesnt work
i am also new to these things not much experienced so if you found any error from my side please help me out.

desc:- i am working on a server client based project where i need the socket.io library
and i have included all the things necessary for it to work

my project works when i try this

```
<script defer src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js "></script>
```

but it doesnt work when i do like this (i saw this almost everywhere in the internet)

```
<script defer src="/socket.io/socket.io.js "></script>
```

++help i also want it to work(deploy) on heroku so please help so that it should not have default ports

any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you add `"/socket.io/socket.io.js"`, it'll try to load that file with your `location.origin` + `"/socket.io/socket.io.js"` and since you don't have a server running in the path `location.origin`, it'll fail loading the `socket.io.js` file.
But
When you add the `address` along with the relative path, it becomes absolute and hence it'll just find the path you mentioned and fetch the `socket.io.js` file available there. ( since your server is running there with socket.io installed )

And for the second question,
once after deploying your application on Heroku, you'll get a link, just join that link with `"/socket.io/socket.io.js"` and that will work.

I hope this answer helps you!
Add a comment if you get any doubt about this. And mark the answer if you find it helpful so that others who are stuck with the same problem can also be benifisiary.

Comment: then how can i add that location.origin to it and for the second answer , did you mean that "/socket.io/socket.io.js" this will work in heroku there will bhi no errors?

Comment: There will be no errors in the heroku.
1. If you are rendering the HTML page with the backend ( heroku ) then there won't be any error.
2. If your HTML page and backend is deployed separately in different domains, then just copy the backend's domain and add it at the beginning of socket.io.js link.

I guess you're rendering HTML page with backend itself. So there won't be any issue.

Comment: again application error it says:: 2022-09-06T17:04:54.787653+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=supritchatioapp.herokuapp.com request_id=76447740-aeb8-443f-afac-107feaf3978f fwd="157.35.10.131" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-09-06T17:04:55.375825+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=supritchatioapp.herokuapp.com request_id=cb2548ab-6478-444e-82da-34a06273c2fa fwd="157.35.10.131" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https      help me